# why ctrl-h and ctrl-l behaves differently in normal mode?

Tags: cursor-movement

In normal mode, I tried `CTRL-H` and `CTRL-L`, and I found that the former worked while the latter didn't do anything at all.

I wonder why their behaviors are not the same?

Answer (score 2):

In normal mode <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> is same as <kbd>h</kbd> -- that is 'move to the left' while <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> means 'clear and redraw the screen', not 'move to the right'. This  <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> behavior is very similar to bash shell. This is useful for example when you have background process printing some stuff while you are using vim in terminal.

Comment: I thought ctrl h was the same as backspace (which happens to work like h)?

Comment: @Ben what you said probably correct. But we use `X` to delete to the left in normal mode, which is a reverse of `x`.  I don't know why vim/vi author not (also) assign `Ctrl-H` for this purpose.

Comment: Because the backspace key sends an escape sequence, like many other keys, which happens to be ctrl h. And it made sense for backspace to move left a character (space moves right one). So it was the choice of backspace functionality that affected ctrl h.

Comment: @Ben perhaps you can put your opinion as separate answer so it can benefit everone else.

Answer (score 0):

In fact <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> is ASCII `0x08`. If you look this up in a ASCII table, it is defined as "backspace". The <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is ASCII `0x7f` (127dec). In ASCII this is defined as "DEL". In UNIX-like environments both keys delete the character to the left of the cursor.

In Vim insert mode, both keys delete the character to the left of the cursor. In normal mode both keys just move the cursor to the left (without deleting).

I don't know how <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> was handled in normal mode of the original Vi, but i think that <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> leads to the same cursor movement is just a coincident.

References:

- Wikipedia [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)
- Wikipedia [Delete Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character)
- Why was hjkl used for cursor movement? See keyboard layout of the [ADM-3A terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A) or [this page](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/).

> BTW: What code the key <kbd>Backspace</kbd> actually sends might be defined 
>   by the terminal. In GNOME-Terminal it can be defined to send `Ctrl-H`, 
>   "ASCII DEL", "Escape Sequence" or "TTY Erase". 
>   AFAIK "ASCII DEL" is the default.

Comment: On FreeBSD, which I believe uses `nvi`, Ctrl-H and Backspace are one and the same. For example, creating a mapping for Ctrl-H (via pressing Ctrl-V Ctrl-H) and pressing Backspace *will* fire that mapping. This is not the case in Vim, as it can differentiate between the two.

Comment: @ZeroKnight This might also be due to terminal settings. See my update.